# How to convert array of string to simple string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have the following JavaScript array of strings:

```
arrayOfString = ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e', 'f'];
```

And I would like to convert this array to an array similar to this:

```
myString = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
```

How I can accomplish that?

Comment: So, you want to split the items like `'b,c'` into `'b', 'c'`…?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg What is the reason to spread the array first. why not `arrayOfString.flatMap(item => item.split(',')`

Comment: Please, either edit your question or your expected output, because in one you ask for a simple string, while in the other you expect an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with `split`, `reduce` and `concat`:

```js
const arrayOfString = ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e', 'f'];
const myString = arrayOfString.map(e => e.split(",")).reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr));
console.log(myString);
```

Explanation:

Use `map` to iterate through the array, then `split` out each letter, then use `reduce` and `concat` as well-supported methods to flatten the resulting multi-dimensional array, and finally assign the result to `myString`.

Comment: I'll add an explanation @Stijn.

Comment: a little overkill, but thumbs up for using reduce/map

Comment: My bad @Cœur - I didn't know that such a rejection option existed. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and `split()`

```js
let arrayOfString = ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e','f'];
let res = arrayOfString.flatMap(x => x.split(','))
console.log(res)
```

If `flatMap()` is not supported by your browser then use `map()` `concat()` and spread operator. Pass the result of `map()` to `concat()` using spread operator.

```js
let arrayOfString = ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e','f'];
let res = [].concat(...arrayOfString.map(x => x.split(',')))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

**Note:** The default separator of `join()` is `comma (,)`

```js
const arrayOfString = ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e', 'f']

const myString = arrayOfString.join().split(',')

console.log(myString)
```

Comment: Nice way dude. You don't need to pass `,` to `join()`. It joins by `,` if no arg is passed.

Comment: @MaheerAli Good Catch

Answer (score 0):

you can use spread operator, map and split

```js
let arr = [];
let input =  ['a', 'b,c', 'd,e', 'f'];
input.map(obj => arr = [...arr,...obj.split(",")])

console.log(arr);
```